# Regex on SHA1 hash

Tags: regex

I have list of SHA1s and i get the results required using the steps below, but was wondering if i could achieve the same thing with a single operation (currently using Notepad++)

```
99972099c60a6481837419c13959842bf7f7f037

Find What:([0-9a-f]{40})
Replace with: \1.source

99972099c60a6481837419c13959842bf7f7f037.source

Find What: (^[0-9a-f]{6})
Replace with: /\1/\1
/999720/99972099c60a6481837419c13959842bf7f7f037.source
```

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 2):

```
Find:    ([0-9a-f]{6})([0-9a-f]{34})
Replace: /\1/\1\2.source
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HWXiED/1) (and explanation)